# NetBeans cannot find stuff in a jar

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm working on a project which wraps some C++ code using SWIG and then need to write a java interface around it. I can do this no problem manually but NetBeans is opaque enough I can't seem to get it to work. I have a C++ project which builds the JNI and then packages the SWIG wrapper Java files and the JNI into a JAR.

I add that JAR to the Java project. It clearly shows up in the GUI, but my main code can't call any of the code contained in the JAR. I've tried every permutation of package names and so on without any luck. I tried to directly set the classpath using compiler flags in NetBeans but couldn't tell if it was actually doing it.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JAR file needs to contain the java class files. It appears to only contain the source files..

Comment: Thanks. Guess I was trying to be to avoid invoking javac in the C++ project but oh well. Follow up question: now NetBeans compiles OK but is having trouble finding the JNI (packaged inside the jar) at run time. Ideas?

Comment: Try `System.load(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource("StopPow/libcStopPow.jnilib").getFile());`